# Download file from Sharepoint online using C# without REST api

Tags: c#, sharepoint-online

Trying to write some code that downloads a file from a sharepoint online site using just a shared document link, eg
https://ourcompanysite.sharepoint.com/:p:/s/CP/EUo3_Xs4SKtAsSZCZxJBXyQBAFRhL3pXz7-sM_F-RTyzcA?e=4%3a85JGQ2&at=9

I have tried System.Net.WebClient, eg

```
using (WebClient loWC = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    
         string lsFileName = "https://companysite.sharepoint.com/:p:/s/CP/EUo3_Xs4SKzcA?e=4%3a85JGQ2&at=9";
    
         Uri loURI = new Uri(lsFileName);
    
         loWC.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myuser@company.com.au", "Pass123");
        
         byte[] loData = null;
        
         ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
    
         ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999;
        
         byte[] loData = loWC.DownloadData(loURI);         
                                        
     }
```

This doesn't work, its fails at loWC.DownloadData with a "403 forbidden error.".  I definately have access to that Sharepoint site with the specified username and pass.

Couple of questions,

Firstly, will that method of passing credentials work when the user name is an email address? I don't have a domain/username.

Secondly, is it possible to download a file (or just get the content) from Sharepoint online in this way without using the Sharepoint REST api?  My understanding is the REST api requires knowledge of the full document library path and name, which I don't have.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to set the appropiate http headers before calling your `DownloadData` method? `loWC.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Other");`

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the authentication issue.  It downloads a file now, but its not the file from that link, its some html page content which I am assuming has scripts to get the correct file.

Comment: That's why `DownloadData` method downloads the resource as a byte array. Use [DownloadFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfile?view=net-7.0) instead `DownLoadData`.